# Rails: How to disable a plugin from loading during startup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-plugins

Is there anyway I can detect a exception and stop a plugin from loading in Rails?

Thanks,
Sivakumar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `config.plugins` option on your `config/environment.rb` to choose which plugins are loaded.

read more here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#rails-general-configuration